# How to make a site "unique" from each user?

Tags: javascript

I have made a "dating app" website where you can like hard-coded users - just an assignment not implemented in real life:).
Whenever a user logs in - which it only can if it has SignUp - and likes a hard-coded match it gets saved via local storage. So whenever an other user logs in, that user has the **exact** same site and liked profiles.
So my question is, how do you save a user action individually on a website - in theory - so not everyone share the same site. Links for articles would also be much appreciated, cause I investigated myself, but couldn't find any usefull articles.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: local storage is well local, so the users would only have the same data if they are using the same computer.

What you can do is store the data in local storage using their username to uniquely identify their data. When you load the data for local storage you search for their username and only use their data.

Comment: Assuming you don't have any kind of back-end, a workaround would be to use a unique username or id as a key to store your data, and each user would read only the data with his unique id. I suggest you look for javascript databse libraries or IndexedBD [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)

Comment: @GregM As this is just for an assignment, I think that's OK, or even the expectation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you don't have a backend and that is why you are using local storage.

logalstorage is a set of (key, value) pairs. You'll need to make the key unique depending on the user that is logged in.

For example:

```
  let user = "Greg"
  localStorage.setItem.(user + "likes", likes);
```

and to get the data later

```
  let likes = localStorage.getItem.(user + "likes");
```

This idea of a unique key is exactly how databases work.